# Right Indentation with Tabbing

Tags: tabbing

I would like to know how to right indent (for the first column only) while using tabbing.
My code is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{ragged2e}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{1cm}\=\hspace{1cm}\=\kill
    300\>g\>Fleisch oder Fisch nach Wahl\\
    1\>EL\>Currypaste, rote\\
    200\>ml\>Wasser\\
    400\>ml\>Kokosmilch\\
    800\>g\>Gemüse nach Wahl\\
    2\>EL\>Fischsauce\\
    2\>EL\>Sojasauce, helle\\
    1\>EL\>Palmzucker oder brauner Rohrzucker\\
    2\>St.\>Peperoni, rot oder grün, schräg geschnitten\\
    2\>St.\>Chilischote(n), kleine scharfe (nach Belieben)\\
    6\>St.\>Thai-Basilikum Blätter\\
    2\>EL\>Rapskernöl oder Erdnussöl
\end{tabbing}
\end{document}
```

But the result should look like this.
[image: Right Indent by the First Column]

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Comment: ok sure. I just think that it will make my code messy.

Comment: Well what you posted is not really a MWE, this is why it looks messy. ;-) Just keep it to the minimum, like I did in my answer and even there when you wouldn't use Umlauts, you could get rid of the `inputenc`.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest, that instead of the `tabbing` environment, you make use of `tabular` and then define the columns as `rll`. A complete example would be:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{rll}
    300 & g & Fleisch oder Fisch nach Wahl\\
    1 & EL & Currypaste, rote\\
    200 & ml & Wasser\\
    400 & ml & Kokosmilch\\
    800 & g & Gemüse nach Wahl\\
    2 & EL & Fischsauce\\
    2 & EL & Sojasauce, helle\\
    1 & EL & Palmzucker oder brauner Rohrzucker\\
    2 & St. & Peperoni, rot oder grün, schräg geschnitten\\
    2 & St. & Chilischote(n), kleine scharfe (nach Belieben)\\
    6 & St. & Thai-Basilikum Blätter\\
    2 & EL & Rapskernöl oder Erdnussöl
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

It results in:
[image]

---

Your additional question asks to keep the first two columns 1cm wide. This can be achieved with the help of the `w` column type provided by the `array` package:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{array} % for 'w' column type

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{@{}
                w{r}{1cm} % 1st col.
                @{\hspace{0.5\tabcolsep}} % only a small amount of sep.
                w{l}{1cm} % 2nd col.
                @{}
                l % 3rd and final col.
                @{}}
    300 & g  & Fleisch oder Fisch nach Wahl\\
      1 & EL & Currypaste, rote\\
    200 & ml & Wasser\\
    400 & ml & Kokosmilch\\
    800 & g  & Gemüse nach Wahl\\
      2 & EL & Fischsauce\\
      2 & EL & Sojasauce, helle\\
      1 & EL & Palmzucker oder brauner Rohrzucker\\
      2 & St.& Peperoni, rot oder grün, schräg geschnitten\\
      2 & St.& Chilischote(n), kleine scharfe (nach Belieben)\\
      6 & St.& Thai-Basilikum Blätter\\
      2 & EL & Rapskernöl oder Erdnussöl
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help. If I may ask one more question: how can I make the first and second column 1cm in length?

Comment: +1. You beat me to this `tabular`-based answer by a couple of minutes. :-) The only thing I'd change in your answer is to reduce the amount of whitespace between the first two columns by inserting, say, `@{\hspace{0.5\tabcolsep}}` between `r` and `l` (and, in the preamble, load the `array` package).

Comment: @Mico do you want to go ahead and do that through an edit? I approve it! And I am happy that I am not the last to a party, at least once. It is sometimes really hard here on TeX.SE to be the first. :-) Especially on weekends at European night time, when there is a swarm of people that are helpful within minutes. ;-)

Comment: @ReynanHenry If it is a new question, please accept this answer and open a new one. If it adds up to this one, please edit this question.

Comment: @TobiBS - I've taken you up on your offer. Feel free to revert. :-)

Comment: @Mico Looks good, thanks for the improvement. I am always a bit undecided on whether it is worth to load another package or not. ;-) But I didn't know about the `w` column type yet, so it seems it's worth it sometimes.

Comment: @Mico everything is good, my question is already answered in this comment section. I appreciate all of your explanations. It really helps me so much.

Answer (score 0):

A tabular would be more flexible and versatile, but if you prefer to use tabbing, you can still achieve what you want using a `\makebox[0pt][r]{..}`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\begin{document}

\begin{tabbing}
\hspace{1cm}\=\hspace{1cm}\=\kill
  \makebox[0pt][r]{300}\>g\> Fleisch oder Fisch nach Wahl\\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{1}\>EL\> Currypaste, rote\\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{200}\>ml\> Wasser\\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{400}\>ml\> Kokosmilch\\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{800}\>g\> Gemüse nach Wahl\\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{2}\>EL\> Fischsauce\\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{2}\>EL\> Sojasauce, helle\\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{1}\>EL\> Palmzucker oder brauner Rohrzucker\\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{2}\>St.\> Peperoni, rot oder grün, schräg geschnitten\\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{2}\>St.\> Chilischote(n), kleine scharfe (nach Belieben)\\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{6}\>St.\> Thai-Basilikum Blätter\\
  \makebox[0pt][r]{2}\>EL\> Rapskernöl oder Erdnussöl
\end{tabbing}

\end{document}
```

[image]